# WooCommerce AJAX add to cart - simple products only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have followed this how to guide for ajax add to cart for single products: https://aceplugins.com/ajax-add-to-cart-button-on-the-product-page-woocommerce/

I have the php in my child themes function.php file and it works as it should.

The problem that i am having is that i only want to use `remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );` when on a simple product only so that it is available for other product types.

I have tried adding it to the `ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler` function like so:

```
function ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler() {
    WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action();
    WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments();

    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );
} 
add_action( 'wc_ajax_ace_add_to_cart', 'ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler' );
add_action( 'wc_ajax_nopriv_ace_add_to_cart', 'ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler' );
```

I've also tried various functions with conditionals with no joy, eg:

```
function remove_cart_action(){
    if ( is_product() ) {
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
    // Remove WC Core add to cart handler to prevent double-add
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 ); 
    }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_cart_action', 20);
```

Any advice would be appreciated - thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code but not sure if it works
You can check it!

```php
function ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler() {
    WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action();
    WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments();

    $product_id = isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ? intval( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) : false;
    if ( $product_id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );
        }
    }
} 
add_action( 'wc_ajax_ace_add_to_cart', 'ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler' );
add_action( 'wc_ajax_nopriv_ace_add_to_cart', 'ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler' );
```